# Getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException for different lists

Tags: c#, console-application

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zERnv.jpg)

So i'm getting this System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException i couldn't figure it out how to fix it. The odd thing is when i remove some of the numbers in "numbers" list it works perfectly. But i need to calculate all of the numbers and i don't know where the problem is. Did a lot of debugging and it is neither out of range nor negative number.
I'm open to any suggestions or changes, thanks.

```
var brickpiece1list1 = new List<int>() { };

int count = 0;

int maxval = 510;

var numbers = new List<int>() { 349, 349, 349, 349, 348, 348, 345, 345, 345, 330, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 325, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 314, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 299, 299, 299, 298, 298, 298, 298, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 280, 280, 280, 280, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 265, 264, 264, 260, 260, 260, 260, 255, 255, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 225, 220, 220, 220, 220, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 199, 199, 199, 199, 198, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 170, 170, 165, 165, 165, 165, 160, 160, 155, 155, 155, 155, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 140, 139, 139, 139, 139, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 124, 124, 124, 124, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 74, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 50, 50, 50, 24, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };



for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count;)
{

  for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Count; j++)
  {

    if (numbers.Count > 2)
    {

     if (numbers[j] < maxval - numbers[i] && numbers[j] + numbers[i] <= maxval)
     {
      int x = numbers[i];
      int y = numbers[j];
      numbers.RemoveAt(i);
      numbers.RemoveAt(numbers.IndexOf(numbers[j]));
      int z = numbers[j] + numbers[i];
      bool test = true;

      for (int t = 0; t < numbers.Count; t++)
      {
       if (numbers[t] < maxval - z && z + numbers[t] <= maxval)
       {
        count++;
        brickpiece1list1.Add(x);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} + {2} = {3} 3 block piece used and block count is: {4} ", numbers[i], numbers[j], numbers[t], z + numbers[t], count);
        numbers.RemoveAt(numbers.IndexOf(numbers[t]));
        test = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Total count is: {0}", count);
        break;
       }
      }
      if (test == true)
      {
       count++;
       brickpiece1list1.Add(numbers[i]);
       Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2} 2 block piece used and block count is: {3} ", numbers[i], numbers[j], z, count);
       Console.WriteLine("Total count is: {0}", count);
      }

     }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Think about what `numbers.RemoveAt(i);` does to the size of the list and what happens if `i` was equal to the previous list size - 1 (i.e. `numbers.Count - 1`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought this way; I'm not increasing the i value so it always takes the 0 index which is the biggest number of list. Then after the if statement it removes the index of i which is 0. It also lowers the list by 1 in every loop. If i use numbers.Count -1 the search algorithm won't work properly. I think i'm missing something or thinking wrongly i don't know.

Comment: After you call `numbers.RemoveAt(i);` the length of `numbers` will be reduced by one. If `i` is `numbers.Count-1` (which happens at the end of the loop) then when you subsequently try to access `numbers[i]` then `i` will be beyond the end of list.

Comment: Your best bet here is to single-step the code in the debugger to see what's happening.